# Looking for calculators to compute all things related to Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I am looking for calculators related to Linear algebra.

I am especially looking for complex calculators that are able to calculate Transformations in matrices,  coordinate system, and anything related.

It would be really helpful if those calculators also show steps towards the solution.

I have already came across these

```
https://www.symbolab.com/
https://www.dcode.fr/matrix-inverse
https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/linear-algebra/
http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi
https://matrixcalc.org/en/vectors.html
https://planetcalc.com/7935/
https://www.hackmath.net/en/calculator/complex-number
```

So it would be great if you have ones that I don't, and again there are a lot that do simple staff like finding the determinant and trivial staff I am looking for the more sophisticated ones.

Comment: https://live.sympy.org/

Comment: You could try [sage](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/modules/sage/modules/vector_space_morphism.html) (free at cocalc.org)